# How do I filter data depending on the values from Sub Collection in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMtAv.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpraD.png)
How can I display only the documents which contain a specific data value in the sub collection.

Comment: Start with the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and [flutter plugin docs](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore).  If you have a specific problem or code that isn't working the way you expect, be sure to include that in your question.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this document in order to improve your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do filtered queries (and I think you are) this doc should suffice.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries

**EDIT**.
Just to clarify, for a subCollection all you got to do is:

```
docRef = db.collection(collection).document(document).collection(subCollection)
```

and then apply the filter as in the docs to this docRef.